# How can I make a graphene supercapacitor?

Tags: electrochemistry, carbon-allotropes

I have heard that a [super capacitor can be made with a dvd burner](http://io9.com/5987086/meet-the-scientific-accident-that-could-change-the-world). What materials do I need to to get and what software for my DVD burner do I need to make this amazing device?

Comment: Could you provide a link to where you heard/read about this? It would help use help you.

Comment: http://io9.com/5987086/meet-the-scientific-accident-that-could-change-the-world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chemistry World UK have made [this YouTube Clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oEFwyoWKXo) that has a professor from UCLA explaining what is needed and how to go about it - even though the video is about 2.5 minutes, but it is a good demonstration.  The associated article is [DVD player burns graphene to disc](http://www.rsc.org/chemistryworld/News/2012/March/graphene-dvd-player-burn-supercapacitor.asp)

Additionally, according to this JensLabs page [DIY Graphene](http://jenslabs.com/2013/03/14/diy-graphene/), it states that the following readily available materials are needed:

> - Graphite oxide
> - Light scribe capable DVD burner
> - Light scribe DVD
> - Substrate
> - Sonicator - the article suggests that a ultrasonic cleaner would suffice
> - Pipette
> - Ion-porous separator
> - Electrolyte